# Calculating the fractal dimension of a Romanesco Broccoli

Tags: fractals

It has been quite a while since I've had some introductions to fractal geometry, but only on special cases, e.g., the Sierpinski triangle and other self similar fractals.

Now I have challenged myself to calculate the fractal dimension of the romanesco broccoli, since it has some self similarity. It is illustrated by the images below:

[image: Behold the Romanesco Broccoli in all it's glory!]

[image: Side view for more information.]

So, my request here is for some references to help me with this goal. If you want to answer with a hint or an important step on this kind problem it is also welcome.

Thanks for the attention and have a good day!

Comment: Just a couple of tips on how I'd approach this: (1) Assume the broccoli is the union of copies of itself with linear scale factors $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$. Can you express the dimension as an implicit function of the $a_i$'s? (I think I know the solution to this, but perhaps you want to figure it out yourself.) (2) Suppose the $a_i$'s are in decreasing order (starting from the base of the broccoli head and spiraling in). How does $a_i$ decay as a function of $i$? (Is it exponential? A power law? Something else?) At some stage this will likely entail pulling out a ruler and measuring. :)

Comment: If you do want a reference for (1) above, look up Moran's Theorem.  https://sci-hub.se/https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5079401

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I'll try this method. And I did laugh when I read the ruler part. Good day to you!